# MySQL: How do I get the AVG value in one column for entries sharing distinct values in another column?

Tags: mysql

In the case of a table as such:

```
id num   grp
1  12.3  group1
2  2.4   group2
3  7.6   group2
4  4.5   group1
5  8.9   group1
6  12.6  group1
7  1.1   group2
8  7.8   group1
```

I would like to output to the result grid an additional column which would have a value of 9.22 in all rows with a grp value of group1, and 3.7 in all rows with a grp value of group2. So, in each case, the average num value of all rows with the same grp value.

I'm still learning MySQL. I think I basically know the components I need (AVG, DISTINCT/GROUP BY, and possibly a self join?), but I'm struggling to find the right way to put them together.

Comment: You have to do a `... JOIN (SELECT AVG(num), grp FROM table GROUP BY grp) AS t2 ON t1.grp = t2.grp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try the query below, using `GROUP BY` of `AVG` and then `JOIN` with the same table, you can get the extra column value with your expectation:

```
SELECT TA.id, TA.num, TA.grp , AG.AvgNum
FROM ( SELECT grp, AVG(num) AS AvgNum
       FROM TableName
       GROUP BY grp ) AG
JOIN  TableName TA ON TA.grp = AG.grp
```

Rextester Demo: [`http://rextester.com/SZW95037`](http://rextester.com/SZW95037)

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it's the most complete one. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to join the table and the query, that returns aggregate values via `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT id, num, avg_num, grp
FROM
  MyTable
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT AVG(num) AS avg_num, grp
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY grp) grouped
USING(grp);
```